# Open PDF in a WPF application at specific bookmark

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have an existing PDF which I want to open at specific bookmarks in a WPF application. Below is the snippet of code I'm using:

```
Dim myProcess As Process = New Process()
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "AcroRd32.exe"
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/n /A ""pagemode=bookmarks&nameddest=Holidays"" ""c:\Classic\Manual\DocumentationManual.pdf"""
myProcess.Start()
```

The PDF opens in bookmark mode but not at the specified destination
bookmark (`Holidays` in the example above).

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Named destinations are not the same as bookmarks in PDF, and I don't know of a parameter to open a specific bookmark.  You would either have to add a named destination or use the page number: `page=n`.